# Minimizing Frobenius norm of the difference between $A$ and $P^\top B P$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, orthogonal-matrices

I have two $n\times n$ real matrices $A$, $B$, not necessarily symmetric. 
Is there any clever way to compute 
$$
\min_P || A - P^{\top} B P ||_F
$$
where $P$ ranges over the group of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: Are the matrices real?

Comment: There are very many ways to do this. Is there some particular class of methods you would like to use?

Comment: Something that is guaranteed to be computationally efficient.